# How can I configure MediaWiki to display numbers in titles?

Tags: mediawiki

We would like to display **numbers** in the **titles** in our MediaWiki wiki.

Specifically: in the **table of contents** numbers are shown like this:

```
 1 Title
   1.1 Subtitle
 2 Another title
```

However, on *the page* the titles (that map to the table of contents) appear like this:

```
 Title
  text
 Subtitle
  text
 Another title
  text
```

That is, no numbers are shown.

**How can we show numbers *in the page contents*?**

There are three possible ways that this could be answered (that I can think of). In our order of preference, they are:

1. Setting per user
2. Setting per page
3. Global setting (for all users)

Comment: Please edit your question to give it consistency. You bounce back and forth between title and page. Which is it?

Comment: @John - I don't know what you mean. The table of contents is first - which shows the title numbers. Then there are titles below (rest of the page) that don't show title numbers, just text.

Comment: Ok, you're talking about title entries in the table of contents but when I read the question and its title it looks like you're talking about page titles, not the table of contents.

Comment: @John - OK, sorry for the confusion and thanks for the clarification. I will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Murphy's Law. Despite Googling for the answer I could not find it *until after* I had posted the question.

The answer comes from: [add numbers to section headings?](http://www.mwusers.com/forums/showthread.php?4073-add-numbers-to-section-headings)

It is: user PREFERENCES -> MISC -> check **Auto-numbering of heading**.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add it by default for all users add a line:

```
$wgDefaultUserOptions['numberheadings'] = 1;
```

to your LocalSettings.php. See [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Auto-number_headings) for reference.

Comment: excellent, thanks! I can't accept this because it wasn't my *first* preference (that was setting per user) but I can upvote! If someone adds setting per page we'll have the set! =:-)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>My Preferences</kbd> --> <kbd>Appearance</kbd> --> <kbd>Auto-number headings</kbd>